# Calculating the Expected Value for a Gambling Game (Randomly Roll 1-100, Basic Expectation Problem)

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

I have a slightly interesting gambling game in mind. You roll from $1-100$ and bet $x$ gold. Here are the rules:

1. Roll  $1-58:$ you lose an additional $x$ gold.
2. Roll $59-98:$ you win an additional $x$ gold.
3. Roll $99-100$: you win an additional $2x$ gold.

$E(x)$ = $(.58)(-x)+(.40)(x)+(.02)(2x)$ = $-0.14x$

EDIT: After an arithmetic correction, you expect to lose fourteen percent of the gambled amount, which seems more reasonable. If anyone can verify that it's correct, I'd appreciate it. An alternate solution I thought of had factors of $2$ and $3$ involved in E(x), but I feel more confident with this one.

Comment: $(.58)(-x)+(.40)(x)+(.02)(2x)$ equals $-0.14x$, not $-0.33x$.

Comment: Thanks! Gosh, arithmetic got me.

Comment: What does "additional" mean here? Is your $E(x)$ just the expected "additional" gain, after I have paid the initial bet? So overall I should expect to lose $1.14x$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I believe. I ultimately want to have a sense of how much gold I'll lose when I bet, so I think this checks out.

Comment: It all depends on what "additional" means.  Such as: do  you bet $x$ so either loose the bet and an *additional* $x$ on (1-58), *or* gain the bet back and either an *additional* $x$ (on 59-98) or an *additional* $2x$ (on 99-100).  If so the expected return on the bet is $$\mathsf E(r)~{=-2x(0.58)+x(0.40)+2x(0.02) \\= -0.72 x}$$